# Change legend tick in image.plot

Tags: r, image, plot

Using this code

```
library(fields)
rot_mat = matrix(round(runif(25)*3+1),5,5)
image.plot(rot_mat,xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", frame.plot=F,
             col = c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'))
```

I get the plot

[image: image.plot of a matrix]

Now I want the number 1,2,3,4 on the right side of the legend to strings, for example "a","b","c","d". I want the numbers to be right next to the color so that the label is clearly connected with the certain color.

The closest I have come is:

```
image.plot(rot_mat,xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", frame.plot=F,
           col = c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'),
           lab.breaks=c('a','b','c','d', ""),
           breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

This gives me the plot

[image: Plot with custom labels]

Which is close but the labels are too far down. You are more than welcome to suggest other methods than image.plot if you think something else is better but I need something that I can use with par(mfrow) so that I can make subplots and it needs to be fast for large (500*500) matrices. The reason I have numbers from 1-4 is that the matrice comes from a comparison of two adjacency matrices and 1-4 is numbers which correspond to true positive, false positive, true negative and false negative "connections".

Answer (score 3):

```
image.plot(rot_mat,xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", frame.plot=F,
           col = c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'), 
           axis.args = list(at = 1:4, labels=c('a','b','c','d')))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't notice that arg.